# Dio Flutter Interceptor

Tags: flutter, interceptor, http-status-code-401, refresh-token, dio

10 requests going synchronously at once, 10 responses from the interceptor returning with a 401 status code on each error in the on error function. How to write it so that 401 comes once in the interceptor?

Comment: There is no simple way to do that, maybe make them async to avoid that situation or make the interceptor call CancelToken of the other requests but you will have to handle that situation too

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.